# Why was a light fixture installed with dry wall anchors?

Tags: electrical, light, anchor

[image]

I came home to a light fixture hanging off the wall today. The light was never attached to the electrical box, instead it was installed with drywall anchors to the edge of the drywall against the box. The drywall was covered with caulk and big pieces of it (caulk) came out with the anchors.

My question is why would someone do this? Is there a reason why you would not install the light to the box? I would think the drywall anchors would be more work than just screwing it into the box. [image][image]

Comment: Is the box attached to a stud, or is it an old work box attached to the drywall?

Comment: It’s between studs. I don’t know the name for it, but it has metal bars on either side of the box that reach to the studs.

Comment: looks like laziness at work

Comment: We cannot answer that question, the only person who can answer that is the person who installed it.

Comment: Is the box loose feeling and pulling out past drywall face when fixture is attached?

Answer (score 1):

I am with everyone's opinion that we can't explain why someone install something wrong. Other than he did not practice standard installation practices, and that probably means that whomever installed the fixture was not an experienced electrician.

What I can tell you is that all of the necessary parts are there in your pictures. First your box looks ok. You can see a lug attaching to the box at the 1/2" knockout in the back indicating a brace. also you have the mounting plate for the fixture. That's the round thing with all of the slots and holes in it. You will find that one set of those holes and slots will line up with the screws in the ears of the box. Then another sets of holes will line up with your fixture.

What I don't see is the ground coming from the box. I hope whoever installed it didn't just cut it off, because that need to be connected up also.

If an electrician or an electrical contractor you need to contact them and have them make it right and if they don't file a complaint the your AHJ.

Good luck.